# How can I write a code to only remove "deerleader" from this list using pop

Tags: list, printing, python-3.8

```
satellites = [["sputnik", "USSR"], \
         ["telstar", "USA"], \
         ["asterix", "France"], \
         ["deerleader", "North Korea"], \
         ["azur", "Germany"]]
print(satellites)
print((satellites).pop(3))
```

I'm trying to figure out how to only remove the name "deerleader" from this list without removing "North Korea" as well. The code I wrote keeps removing both and I only need "deerleader" removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can index the list `[3]` and the pop the first element `(0)`:

```py
satellites = [
    ["sputnik", "USSR"],
    ["telstar", "USA"],
    ["asterix", "France"],
    ["deerleader", "North Korea"],
    ["azur", "Germany"],
]

satellites[3].pop(0)
print(satellites)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    ["sputnik", "USSR"],
    ["telstar", "USA"],
    ["asterix", "France"],
    ["North Korea"],
    ["azur", "Germany"],
]
```